# HTML POST request method returns status 200 and file doesn't update

Tags: javascript, html, post, http-status-code-404

I am working on a system to upload a picture to the server.
When the file doesn't exist on the server the client receives status code 404.
When the server does have a file called in the same name as the file that the client requests to update, It receives status code 200 but the file doesn't update on the server, just no change at all.

Code:

HTML input:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="pfp-upload">
    <p>Please upload your new profile picture:</p>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="new-pfp" accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg">
</form>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" title="Popover title" data-content="" onclick="updatePfp(document.getElementById('pfp-upload') ,document.getElementById('new-pfp'))">Save changes</button>
```

JavaScript code running when the submit button is clicked:

```
async function updatePfp(form, pfp) {
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    let photo = pfp.files[0];
    console.log(photo);
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("POST", "/media/" + photo.name, true);
    oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
           if (oReq.status == 200) {
             console.log("File uploaded!");
           } else {
             console.log("There was an error (" + oReq.status + ") while sending the file!");   
           }
      };
    oReq.send(formData);
}
```

Console output when the file doesn't exist on the server:

```
File {name: "mainmenu.png", lastModified: 1567069340052, lastModifiedDate: Thu Aug 29 2019 12:02:20 GMT+0300 (Israel Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 1617, …}
POST http://domainCensored/media/mainmenu.png 404 (Not Found)
There was an error (404) while sending the file!
```

Console output when the file exists on the server:

```
File {name: "mainmenu.png", lastModified: 1567069340052, lastModifiedDate: Thu Aug 29 2019 12:02:20 GMT+0300 (Israel Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 1617, …}
File uploaded!
```

After that output nothing changed on the server.

**EDIT:**
After some steps, I got the following:

JavaScript code:

```
async function updatePfp(form, pfp) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    let photo = pfp.files[0];
    formData.append('myFile', photo);
    console.log(photo);
    fetch('/media/' + photo.name, {
         method: 'POST',
         body: formData,
    }).then(response => { 
         return response.text();
    })
    .then(data => {
         console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
         console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Console output (when the file with the same name is on the server):

```
File {name: "mainmenu.png", lastModified: 1567069340052, lastModifiedDate: Thu Aug 29 2019 12:02:20 GMT+0300 (Israel Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 1617, …}
```

After that line, there is another blank line, chrome says it's from this line:

```
console.log(data);
```

This still doesn't work.

Comment: The JS functions is only testing if the POST queried string gets a response from the server, it is not actually uploading the file

Comment: then what do I do?

Comment: By chance are you using NodeJS as a backend handler?

Comment: I don't see a handler there, in HTML forms, usually the "action" attribute sets the value for the form handler

Comment: Later on there is a send button, which uses the onclick attribute to run the updatePfp method. I will update the post so you can see it's code, I am using Bootstrap modal to make this, this form is inside the modal. I don't know what is being used as the backend handler, since I am using a web hosting which only gives me permission to access the files I upload to the hosting, no information about the handlers or anything about the server-side sadly (except for the domain of course...).

Comment: Ok so, I did some debugging, and it turns out the server doesn't respond anything, as you said. Is it because I only upload the file without content-type and content-length?
https://prnt.sc/qz34r6

Comment: I haven't heard about uploading images without a backend handler, I saw a few examples of JS snippets used to upload images using an AJAX call back, but they require to enable a service in the backend or to submit the queried file to a form handler, some of them may be coded using PHP a backend server language

Comment: For example you may read about the usage of the Fetch API with NodeJS -> https://flaviocopes.com/file-upload-using-ajax/

Comment: ok I will try switching to this.

Comment: ok so I changed the system to the system provided in the link you sent, I updated the post to have the current code and console output. There is this weird blank line which says it's from `console.log(data);`... but I don't really know

Comment: If you read the post the example is using NodeJS and requires to install an Express file-upload module

Comment: The file upload is still handled in the backend, JS just sent the request to the handler

Comment: I don't have access to the machine hosting it, when I added the line `import fileupload from 'express-fileupload';`, I receive an error (Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module). What do I do to download it?